# pull shell script auto complete options from text file

Tags: bash, shell, autocomplete

I have a program that looks up a file that contains a host name, and a phone number. when the host name is entered as the only sys arg, the program opens up minicom and dials to it(after doing a few other things). What i am trying to do it set up my script so i can auto complete the sys arg as any of the possible host names contained within the file. I've seen other projects out there that are kind of similar but not quite right for what I'm trying to do and have not gotten them to work.

source file example:

hostname   5555555555

hostname   5555555555

hostname   5555555555

etc.. 123 more times

Comment: i have tried the methods described on http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/tabexpansion.html. i made an edit to the question since the comment doesn't really format it right

Comment: Which of those methods specifically? Show us your attempt. Have you looked at the documentation for the `complete` builtin?

Comment: shell script:

_UseGetOpt-2 ()   
{                
  local cur

  contents=$(cat dialhosts)
  
  COMPREPLY=()   # Array variable storing the possible completions.
  cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}

  case "$cur" in
    -*)
    COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W '$contents' -- $cur ) );;
  esac

  return 0
}


put as first line in the dialer shell script:  

complete -F _UseGetOpt-2 -o dialhosts ./UseGetOpt-2.sh

Comment: ive looked at the complete builtin at https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html. when i try complete with -W it just displays the help menu

Comment: How did you try using `-W`? Did you give `-W` a wordlist? How did you create that wordlist argument? Did you look at `-C` or `-F`?

Comment: select/copy your code in the comment above, edit your question, paste code into an appropriate place in your question, Format code so it is readable,  then select code with mouse and click the `{}` tool at the top right of the edit box. It should take less than a minute. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working version of your function - only the value of `$contents` had to be corrected:

```
_UseGetOpt-2 () { local cur contents=$(sed 's/\(.*\) .*/-\1/' dialhosts)
COMPREPLY=() # Array variable storing the possible completions.
cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
case "$cur" in -*) COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W '$contents' -- $cur ) );;
esac
return 0
}
```

Activate it with the command

```
complete -F _UseGetOpt-2 UseGetOpt-2.sh
```